# API to provide Apple App Store ratings from within an iPhone application

Tags: ios4

I have created an application for the iPhone with many features and would like to add a 'rating feature' to it. The user can then, from within my application, provide an Apple App Store rating -- so that my application can be shown at the top.

Does anyone know how to add this feature to an iPhone app?

Comment: Thanks Chris for making it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have the user rate your application in the App Store from within your application. Instead you can link to your application in the App Store (create an NSURL and use openURL to open it) so that users can provide a rating there. To get the correct link to your app, find it in the App Store and select *Copy Link* from the menu directly under your application's icon.

Comment: I read about this NSURL in previously asked questions. But do not know how to get this URL? Do i need to wait until my application get approved or it can be done at the time of uploading the build file at app store. Is there any tutorial or guide that could help to learn it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an API such as iRate https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate
It redirects the user to the appropriate place in the App store and provides some logic for prompting her to rate the app based on usage time and frequency.